# Why the UILongPressGestureRecognizer in custom UIWindow is not reflecting in UIWebview of the application?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have implemented a custom `UIWindow`, this will be my main window. I have added a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to it. All the views in the application responds to this except the `UIWebView`. I am bit confused on this peculiar problem.

Below is the way of my implementation of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` in `UIWindow`,

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressAction:)];
        [longPress setMinimumPressDuration:3];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Could any one reason out for this problem? How to resolve this?

Thanks !

Comment: UIWebview has its own private views and they handle the gesture recognisers by themselves. This may be hampering your window to respond to the long press.

Comment: @Puneet How to subside these gesture recognizers to make my UIWindow to respond for the same?

Comment: I tried the way mentioned by Avi Tsadok below and it worked. Also if you do not want UIWebview to handle any gestures, just set its userInteractionEnabled property to NO.

Comment: @Puneet _longGesture - Is this the reference of the UILongPressGestureRecognizer that I have mentioned in custom UIWindow?

Comment: Yes it is. In your case the reference of UILongGestureRecogniser you have created is by name longPress.

Comment: @Puneet Please find my comment to the answer of Avi Tsadok. Please suggest !

Comment: It should work. Ok try one more thing, set userInteractionEnabled property on webview to NO and then check whether it is working. If yes, then the issue will be solved by the below mentioned code otherwise we need to keep looking.

Comment: No Its not working @Puneet

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView has a scrollview inside it, with it's own gestures.
Basically, you have a reference to those gestures:

```
_webView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer;
```

So, you can create a condition between those two gestures:

```
[_webView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:_longGesture];
```

Haven't tried it myself, but maybe it will work.

Comment: _longGesture - Is this the reference of the UILongPressGestureRecognizer that I have mentioned in UIWindow?

Comment: _longGesture is the reference to the long press gesture.
Tell me if it worked for you

Comment: Tried as below, but its not working. Please suggest !

EBaseUIWindow *baseWindow = (EBaseUIWindow *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
    [webview.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:[baseWindow longPress]];